# table fixed header not working

Tags: jquery, css

I have a table with large number of rows, i want to set fixed header while scrolling.

I am trying with the below code, but it is not working.

```js
 (function ($) {
    $.fn.fixedHeader = function () {
        return this.each(function () {
            var $this = $(this),
               $t_fixed;

            function init() {
                $this.wrap('<div class="container" />');
                $t_fixed = $this.clone();
                $t_fixed.find("tbody").remove().end().addClass("floatingHeader").insertBefore($this);
                resizeFixed();
            }
            function resizeFixed() {
                $t_fixed.find("th").each(function (index) {
                    $(this).css("width", $this.find("th").eq(index).outerWidth() + "px");
                });
            }
            function scrollFixed() {

                var offset = $(this).scrollTop(),
                tableOffsetTop = $this.offset().top,
                tableOffsetBottom = tableOffsetTop + $this.height() - $this.find("thead").height();
                if (offset < tableOffsetTop || offset > tableOffsetBottom) {
                    $t_fixed.hide();

                }
                else if (offset >= tableOffsetTop && offset <= tableOffsetBottom && $t_fixed.is(":hidden")) {
                    $t_fixed.show();
                }
                resizeFixed();
                init();
            }
            $(window).resize(resizeFixed);
            $(window).scroll(scrollFixed);
            init();
        });
        // $.fn.fixMe = function(){}; // prevent the function from a second firing 
    };
})(jQuery);


$(window).load(function () {
    $(".stickyHeader").fixedHeader();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <table style="width:100%" class="stickyHeader">
        <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Points</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Eve</td>
            <td>Jackson</td>
            <td>94</td>
        </tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr><tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
</tr>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I know this can be done using CSS but I want to do this using javascript/jquery only,

Comment: It would make more sense to use a combination of jQuery *and* CSS styling to do this. Why are you against using CSS at all? Technically you can't do this without at least applying inline styles as you need to change the way the header is rendered.

Comment: i agree with you but in our project they are suggesting to do it that way, i have an updated jsBin with a problem where when i scroll to top of the page i see two headers showing up. I dont want the header at the top of page when scrolled to top of page.   http://jsbin.com/zifimeyuda/1/edit?html,css,js,output